# How do I reauth a user with firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to reauthenticate a user, and am using the code from firebase docs.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

```
import { getAuth, reauthenticateWithCredential } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
const user = auth.currentUser;

// TODO(you): prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
const credential = promptForCredentials();

reauthenticateWithCredential(user, credential).then(() => {
  // User re-authenticated.
}).catch((error) => {
  // An error ocurred
  // ...
});
```

I don't know what credential variable is suppose to be. The promptForCredentials() is not defined anywhere in the docs.

I have tried EmailAuthCredential with no luck.

```
const credential = EmailAuthCredential.credential("a@gmail.com", "!Abc123");
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: What happened when you tried to create `EmailAuthCredential.credential`? Any error message?

Comment: I think it is from only the namespaced API, and not the current treeshakable modular API because this is the error msg: firebase_auth__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.EmailAuthCredential.credential is not a function

Comment: It looks like I was using the wrong  one. It should be  ```EmailAuthProvider.credential()``` and not ```EmailAuthCredential.credential()```